# как сделать юнит-тест на c++ для параметра типа double, чтобы сделать проверку на NAN

Tags: eclipse

как сделать юнит-тест на c++ для параметра типа double, чтобы сделать проверку на NAN

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan